# ¿Cómo se puede crear un ejecutable en netbeans para un programa escrito en C?

Tags: c, netbeans

Tengo escrito un programa en C y me gustaría poder crear un ejecutable de consola para compartirlo y que la gente lo pueda usar. La cosa es que tengo el ejecutable y a mi me funciona en mi PC, pero al pasarle el .exe a un amigo, le salta un mensaje en el que dice que le faltan archivos .dll. ¿Cómo he de crearlo para que no surja ese problema?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes 3 opciones.

1. Compilar tu archivo con bibliotecas estáticas (no se que compilador estás usando pero debe ser posible con cualquiera).
2. Distribuir las bibliotecas con las que te enlazas de forma manual ( hay varias utilidades que te ayudan a buscar cuales son).
3. Utilizar alguna de esas herramientas para crear instaladores y hacer un instalador para tu programa que por supuesto incluya las bibliotecas necesarias.